# Flutter 3D three_dart relate screen touch position to 3D coordinates

Tags: flutter, 3d, touch

Can anyone point me to information on touching the screen with three_dart, flutter_gl, and three_dart_jsm and relating that to 3D coordinates? I realize that there is an infinite set of 3D coodinates, but usually it is given as a direction from the camera. eg Unity has Ray = Camera.screenPointToRay(touch.position).
I am looking at the example code with three.dart, and file webxr_vr_dragging.dart looks to be what I am looking for, but the source code has been commented out (maybe suggestion does not work), and I cannot get it to work. Any suggestions on where to look?

Comment: I am working on a 'not very user friendly' work-around. Using camera.up, and cross product of camera.up and camera.position, I can draw a 'pointer-target' on the screen. To fire the projectile I will use a direction from the camera.position to the pointer-target. I can use this until a better way is found to tap the screen, and get the direction from the camera to the tap point

Comment: I do have something I think is working. Code is a mess at moment, but will put something here when I can clean it up